How do I separate a blobbed object into distinct limbs?
Preface, this is my first time on this SE, I don't know how to ask this question in a short way, and I'm very new to Blender.
I've used an AI 3D model generator to generate a model from an image, but the model has some shortcomings, first of which I'm trying to deal with is to "shave" the model and separate his arms and legs from himself and what he's sitting on. However, I feel like using the delete vertex function alone wouldn't solve the issue, and using the crease tool in the sculpting tab only pushes stuff around, not actually separating the arm from, say, his thigh that it's resting on. To restate, how do you separate a premade model's limbs from itself? As a side note, I have attempted to detach and resculpt the right arm, to modest success, but it's very slow and inefficient, and I have no idea what I'm doing, so other suggestions are welcome.
As requested, multiple screenshots of the model:




It's hard to tell without the object, maybe show some screenshots of the wireframe? You could select an edge loop and press V to rip but the selection of the edge loop may be difficult, depending on the topology

@moonboots Fair nuf. The wireframe is pretty dense, but I'll give it a shot.

You don't. AI generated models are simply not good enough quality yet. If you think you struggle with this because you lack some knowledge or skill in using Blender,  that's not it. Experienced users would struggle with this the same way, because those models are simply no good yet. That's why we still do 3d modelling ourselves. There is no good answer for what you want to do. We can probably tell you some tools to use, but it will still most likely look terrible and will not be usable for many purposes.

I agree with Martynas I would vote to close this question as not suitable here as it cannot get any good answers.

I’m voting to close this question

I would argue otherwise, since I've had some success with selecting vaguely border vertices, deleting them, then using beauty fill on the outline.

In any case, if you want any meaningful help, you should share some clear screenshots of the model. The idea is to show clearly what the model is so the current doesn't seem to be useful at all.

@Fair enough. I'll get to that either later today or tomorrow, since I'm out of town.

You can try masking and separating different parts or doing retopology, it looks unusable...
